# Where does "Included in Block" value comes from?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, confirmations

I was exploring transactions inside of a blockchain using  [this site](https://www.blockchain.com), and inside of a transaction I noticed there is attribute called `Included in Block` and its description is: `block this transaction is mined and confirmed in`. 
(I don't know does it matter but, transaction I was looking is [this one](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/8088eeadbb0c6cbc6cc87ffacc05045f50195bd3837ec392a894465693578b57))

---

I was wondering, how is this attribute populated? The reason of my question is that I was exploring how can you, by looking at transaction inside of your UTXO, check in which block transaction was included (and then I found this attribute). Is this the right way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering, how is this attribute populated?

The site uses an index that simply remembers this information. If a block B is seen that contains a transaction T, an entry is stored in the database that signifies "transaction T is in block B".

> by looking at transaction inside of your UTXO, check in which block transaction was included (and then I found this attribute)

The UTXO set does not contain this information, nor can it be efficiently requested from arbitrary nodes in the network.